# Reference request: Functions of bounded variation in one real variable

Tags: reference-request, real-analysis, geometric-measure-theory

Is there a good reference for facts and theorems about BV real valued functions? I’m looking for something with much more than say Stein and Shakarchi 3, or Evans and Gariepy. Thanks!

Comment: What kind of result are you interested in? in 1D the theory of BV functions essentially reduces to the theory of monotone functions, which is pretty restrictive

Comment: Just everything there might be to know about them. Does BV pretty much imply monotone?

Comment: @JamesBaxter: BV means "difference of two increasing". (There's a lovely old book in Polish on that subject, by Łojasiewicz. I do not thing it has been translated into English, though).

Comment: The following book is worth looking at if you're interested in classical results (i.e. early to mid 20th century): Rangachary Kannan and Carole King Krueger, [**Advanced Analysis on the Real Line**](https://www.amazon.com/dp/038794642X), Universitext series, Springer-Verlag, 1996, x + 259 pages.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The following book has a nice and long chapter of BV functions in one variable:

**G. Leoni**, *A First Course in Sobolev Spaces* Graduate Studies in Mathematics
Volume: 181.

Also an excellent book covering a great deal of the material is:

**I. P. Natanson,** 
*Theory of functions of a real variable.* 
Translated by Leo F. Boron with the collaboration of Edwin Hewitt. Frederick Ungar Publishing Co., New York, 1955.

Answer (score 0):

The book *Gordon, Russell A.*, The integrals of Lebesgue, Denjoy, Perron, and Henstock, Graduate Studies in Mathematics. 4. Providence, RI: American Mathematical Society (AMS). xi, 395 p. (1994). [ZBL0807.26004](https://zbmath.org/?q=an:0807.26004). has a lot of material on BV functions in one variable and various generalizations of BV.